# Find the least square solution and optimal least square solution of the linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the least square solution and optimal least square solution of the linear system:

$$x_1 + 2x_3 = 1$$
$$x_2 +3x_3 = 0$$
$$-x_1 + x_2 + x_3 =0$$
$$-x_2 -3x_3 =1$$

Letting $A$ be the matrix of coefficents, I get that $A^*A$ is

$$A^*A =\left(\begin{array}{rrr} 2 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & 3 & 7 \\
1 & 7 & 23 \end{array}\right)$$

which is not invertible. How can I get the least square solution then? Can someone help me with this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct:

$$A^*A =\left(\begin{array}{rrr} 2 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & 3 & 7 \\
1 & 7 & 23 \end{array}\right)$$

Since you have a singular result, you will likely have infinite solutions.

Use Gaussian elimination to arrive at:

$$x_1 = \dfrac 25 - 2 x_3~, x_2 = -\dfrac 15 - 3x_3~, x_3 = \mbox{free variable}$$

For example, take $x_3 = \dfrac{1}{70}$,

Answer (score 1):

You want the least-squares solution of
$$
                \left[\begin{array}{rrr}1 & 0 & 2 \\
                                        0 & 1 & 3 \\
                                       -1 & 1 & 1 \\
                                        0 & -1 & -3 \end{array}\right]x
     =\left[\begin{array}{r}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right] 
$$
What this means is that you want to minimize the distance between the two sides. Let $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$, $c_{3}$ denote the column vectors of the coefficient matrix. The following is orthogonal to $c_1$:
$$
       c_{2}' = c_{2}-\frac{(c_2,c_1)}{(c_1,c_1)}c_1=c_2+\frac{1}{2}c_1
    =\left[\begin{array}{c} 1/2 \\ 1 \\ 1/2 \\ -1 \end{array}\right]
$$
And the following is orthogonal to $c_1$, $c_2$:
$$
          c_{3}'=c_3-\frac{(c_3,c_1)}{(c_1,c_1)}c_1
-\frac{(c_3,c_2')}{(c_2',c_2')}(c_1+\frac{1}{2}c_2) \\
    = c_{3}-\frac{1}{2}c_1-\frac{15/2}{5/2}(c_2+\frac{1}{2}c_1) \\\
    = c_{3}-2c_1 -3c_2 = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\0\\0\\0\end{array}\right].
$$
Now we know that $x_1=-2, x_2=-3, c_3=1$ is in the null space of the original problem, which makes the least squares solution non-unique. So we'll choose a particular least squares solution to minimize $x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}+x_3^{2}$. In other words, there are two minimization problems required to solve this problem.

Let $c_{4}$ denote the column vector on the right. A best solution $x$ is where
$$
    c_{4} - \frac{(c_4,c_1)}{(c_1,c_1)}c_1-\frac{(c_4,c_2')}{(c_2',c_2')}(c_2+\frac{1}{2}c_1) \\
       = c_4 -\frac{1}{2}c_1-\frac{-1/2}{5/2}(c_2+\frac{1}{2}c_1) \\
       = c_4 -\frac{2}{5}c_1+\frac{1}{5}c_2.
$$
Therefore, a least squares solution is
$$
          x = \left[\begin{array}{c}2/5 \\ -1/5 \\ 0\end{array}\right]
$$
But we may vary this over the null space of the matrix
$$
          x=\left[\begin{array}{c}2/5 \\ -1/5 \\ 0\end{array}\right]
          +\alpha\left[\begin{array}{c}2 \\ 3 \\ -1\end{array}\right]
$$
The solution vector of smallest length is where $\alpha$ is chosen so that the above is orthogonal to the second vector on the right:
$$
      x=\left[\begin{array}{c}2/5 \\ -1/5 \\ 0\end{array}\right]-\frac{1/5}{14}\left[\begin{array}{c}2 \\ 3 \\ -1\end{array}\right]
    = \left[\begin{array}{r}13/35 \\ -17/70 \\1/70\end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: @PedroAlvarès : Did you look at my solution? We have the equation $Ax=y$, and I found the minimum length $x$ that minimizes $\|Ax-y\|$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the 'best' solution out of those possible, I believe people use the [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $A$.  The coefficient matrix ($n\times m$) is broken down into rotation ($m\times m$), scaling ($n\times m$), and second rotation ($n\times n$) matrices.  In particular,

$$ A = VLU^* $$

where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices and the diagonal of $L$ holds the singular values of $A$ (see link).  Then the 'pseudoinverse' of $A$ is formed by the product $U \tilde L V^*$ where $\tilde L$ is an $m\times n$ matrix whose diagonal zeros match those of $L$ and whose nonzero diagonal entries are the inverses of those in $L$.  Apply the pseudoinverse matrix to the image vector $[1 ~~ 0 ~~ 0 ~~ 1]^T$ to find the least squares solution (the vector whose image under $A$ is closest to the desired image vector in euclidean distance).

Comment: Sure you can, see page 407 (analysis of variance problems): http://www.math.usu.edu/powell/pseudoinverses.pdf

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your post and comment - are you saying that there are infinite solutions that all minimize $$ \| Ax - b \| ?$$

Comment: No, he is asking two questions if I am reading it correctly. For the least squares, he has a singular matrix and this can lead to infinite solutions. He is also asking for the optimal solution which I think you are addressing. My answer shows both results, although I did not show the details of how I chose $x_3$. However, that $x_3$ gives the optimal for the variables (which is from the infinite set of solutions).

Comment: I see. So taking $x_3 = 0$ in your solution will lead to the same solution as my method, is that right?

Comment: Yes. Although I would say the problem could have been more clearly written. When I first saw the title, I was asking myself, okay, what is the Op really asking and maybe they are not sure. Regards.